# Separation of variables and using differentiation to verify solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

[image]

So I was able to come to the implicit solution of

$${y^2} - \ln ({y^2}) + {e^{{x^2}}} = 2$$

and then the example in the book suggests that I differentiate in order to check this is true. I tried to do this and maybe I'm approaching an implicit solution incorrectly, but first I put the $~y$'s to one side and the $~x$'s to the other again.

$${y^2} - \ln ({y^2}) =  - {e^{{x^2}}} + 2$$
I differentiated with respect to $~y~$ on the one side and with respect to $~x~$ on the other.

$$\left(2y - \frac{2}{y}\right)\frac{dy}{dx} =  - 2x{e^{{x^2}}}$$

and I guess you could plug in $~y=1~$ and $~x=0~$ as the initial condition suggests, but I am concerned this is not what the book intended when it says

"You can check this by differentiating and rewriting to get the original equation."

The original equation given was:

$$xydx + {e^{ - {x^2}}}({y^2} - 1)dy = 0$$

I would like to be able to check my work after seperating and solving with initial conditions; but I want to be sure I have the right idea with this example.

My question is, did I differentiate $${y^2} - \ln ({y^2}) + {e^{{x^2}}} = 2$$

correctly in order to verify this? I am not sure.

Comment: If $y = y(x)$ then $$(\ln (y^{2}))' = (2 \ln y)' = \frac{2 \color{red}{y'}}{y}$$ and $$(y^{2})' = 2 y \color{red}{y'}$$

Comment: I edit you question and now it looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the result it is simpler to proceed as below :

Differentiate the implicite equation 
$$y^2-\ln(y^2)+e^{x^2}=2\tag 1$$
$d(y^2)=2y\,dy$

$d(\ln(y^2))=\frac{2}{y}dy$

$d(e^{x^2})=2x\,e^{x^2}dx$

$$d\big(y^2-\ln(y^2)+e^{x^2}\big)=2y\,dy-\frac{2}{y}dy+2x\,e^{x^2}dx=0$$

$$\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)dy+x\,e^{x^2}dx=0$$

$$xy\,dx+e^{-x^2}\left(y^2-1\right)dy=0$$
This is exactly the original ODE. Thus the result Eq.$(1)$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared things up significantly! You rock!